# Saving an image from text file providing image url's in python

Tags: python, urllib2

```
import urllib2
import urllib
import json
import urlparse

def main():

    f = open("C:\Users\Stern Marketing\Desktop\dumpaday.txt","r")
    if f.mode == 'r':
        item = f.read()
        for x in item:
            urlParts = urlparse.urlsplit(x)
            filename = urlParts.path.split('/')[-1]
            urllib.urlretrieve(item.strip(), filename)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()`
```

Looks like script still not working properly, I'm really not sure why... :S 
Getting lots of errors...

Comment: You shouldn't check the mode you just passed and you should close the file. `img` in your code is a file-like object you can just read it as a binary file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
urllib.urlretrieve("x", "0001.jpg")
```

This will try to download from the (static) URL `"x"`.

The URL you actually want to download from is within the *variable* `x`, so you should write your line to reference that variable:

```
urllib.urlretrieve(x, "0001.jpg")
```

Also, you probably want to change the target filename for each download, so you don’t keep on overwriting it.

---

Regarding your filename update:

[`urlparse.urlsplit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlsplit) is a function that takes an URL and splits it into multiple parts. Those parts are returned from the function, so you need to save it in some variable.

One part is the `path`, which is what contains the file name. The path itself is a string on which you can call the [`split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method to separate it by the `/` character. As you are interested in only the last part—the filename—you can discard everything else:

```
url = 'http://www.dumpaday.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/funny-160.jpg'
urlParts = urlparse.urlsplit(url)
print(urlParts.path) # /wp-content/uploads/2013/12/funny-160.jpg

filename = urlParts.path.split('/')[-1]
print(filename) # funny-160.jpg
```

---

It should work like this:

```
import urllib2
import urllib
import json
import urlparse

def main():
    with open("C:\Users\Stern Marketing\Desktop\dumpaday.txt","r") as f:
        for x in f:
            urlParts = urlparse.urlsplit(x.strip())
            filename = urlParts.path.split('/')[-1]
            urllib.urlretrieve(x.strip(), filename)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()`
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, for everyone who commented, I was wondering, where you suggest to take this into, I mean, it's not only the url ended filename but also, sometimes it can be .jpg sometimes .png etc... !? any idea what to look into?

Comment: You can use [`urlparse.urlsplit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlsplit) to split the URL into its parse and then use a simple `str.split('/')[-1]` to get the filename of the path.

Comment: Thanks again, I'm newbie to python so This might look like dumb questions.. but this is what I came up with :

Comment: f = open("C:\Users\Stern Marketing\Desktop\dumpaday.txt","r")
 if f.mode == 'r':
    item = f.read()
    for x in item:
     urllib.urlparse.urlsplit(item)
     file_name = str.split('/')[-1]
     print file_name #for testing purpose
#     urllib.urlretrieve(item, file_name)

Comment: Having a hard to to post the code so it would look well to this comments section :(

Comment: You can update your question if you want to add new information.

Comment: Thanks, I just did please recheck Poke. appreciate it.

Comment: I've added urllib2. beofre the urlparse.urlsplit(url) because it didn't work, also, my loop seems to run only for the last img url, and getting stuck ... updating code once again , sorry for all this questions.

Comment: Oh, you will need to add `import urlparse` somewhere at the top.

Comment: Great, that helped me so I could remove the urllib2 , but still when running the print filename I'm getting a huge list of funny-163.jpg
funny-163.jpg
funny-163.jpg
funny-163.jpg
funny-163.jpg
funny-163.jpg
funny-163.jpg
funny-163.jpg
funny-163.jpg
funny-163.jpg
funny-163.jpg
funny-163.jpg
funny-163.jpg
funny-163.jpg
funny-163.jpg
funny-163.jpg

Comment: `urlParts = urlparse.urlsplit(item)` you keep running the split on `item` but you should run it on `x` which is the content of each line as you loop through it.

Comment: h
t
t
p
:


w
w
w
.
d
u
m
p
a
d
a
y
.
c
o
m

w
p
-
c
o
n
t
e
n
t

u
p
l
o
a
d
s

2
0
1
3

1
2

f
u
n
n
y
-
1
6
0
.
j
p
g


h
t
t
p
:


w
w
w
.
d
u
m
p
a
d
a
y
.
c
o
m

w
p
-
c
o
n
t
e
n
t

u
p
l
o
a
d
s

2
0
1
3

1
2

f
u
n
n
y
-
1
6
1
.
j
p
g


h
t
t
p
:


w
w
w
.
d
u
m
p
a
d
a
y
.
c
o
m

w
p
-
c
o
n
t
e
n
t

u
p
l
o
a
d
s

2
0
1
3

1
2

f
u
n
n
y
-
1
6
2
.
j
p
g


h
t
t
p
:


w
w
w
.
d
u
m
p
a
d
a
y
.
c
o
m

w
p
-
c
o
n
t
e
n
t

u
p
l
o
a
d
s

2
0
1
3

1
2

f
u
n
n
y
-
1
6
3
.
j
p
g

Comment: Changed there the item to x and that's what happened it gave me a new line for each char ....

Comment: I think the urlsplit should be on item ?! confused

Comment: Oh well, you read the whole file—as a string—into `item`, so you are iterating over the characters. Either use the `splitlines` approach from the beginning, or iterate over the *file* to make `x` be each line.

Comment: Oh Oops , someone here mentioned it should be fine, I'll change it back to readlines

Comment: Well yeah, it is; you can do `for x in f: …` instead of `for x in f.splitlines():` – but reading everything using `f.read()` will just give you a big text.

Comment: Would you mind joining [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) so we can solve the remaining issues there? It’s getting a bit complicated here :)

Comment: I wish, it says I need 20 reputation to join the chat :(

Comment: Oh right; meh. Well, in the current code in the question, remove `item = f.read()` and write `for x in f` instead of `for x in item`.

Comment: Thanks , still getting this error :     urllib.urlretrieve(f.strip(), filename)
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: I’ve just posted a correct version now; it should work like that.

Comment: tfp = open(filename, 'wb')
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: 'funny-160.jpg\n'

Comment: Changed my solution to run an additional `strip` on `x` when urlsplitting it. It really should work now ^^"

Comment: OMG thank you thank you thank you ! I understand everything aswell except for the .stripe() , care to explain in 30 seconds what that function does?    Thanks again!

Comment: `strip` just removes all leading and trailing whitespace (spaces, tabs, line breaks) from a string. And you’re welcome! Remember to give back and upvote helpful answers and accept the one that solved your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `readlines` method of file objects returns lines with a trailing newline character (`\n`).

Change your loop to the following:

```
# By the way, you don't need readlines at all. Iterating over a file yields its lines.
for x in fl:
    urllib.urlretrieve(x.strip(), "0001.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that loops over images indexed 160 to 171. You can adjust as needed. This creates a url from the base, opens it via `urllib2` and saves it as a *binary file*.

```
import urllib2 
base_url = "http://www.dumpaday.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/funny-{}.jpg"
for n in xrange(160, 170):
    url = base_url.format(n)

    f_save = "{}.jpg".format(n)
    req = urllib2.urlopen(url)

    with open(f_save,'wb') as FOUT:
        FOUT.write(req.read())
```